# Uploading to a PPA using quickly

Tags: ppa, quickly, launchpad

I am trying to participate in ubuntu showdown. I followed Jono's tutorial to do a browser using quickly.

I did some modifications including choosing license (gpl v3), putting my name in copy right ( without special spanish charecters since quicky does not like it)

$quickly run to make sure it worked

I used bazaar to commit a change with a line of comment.

I packaged it using quickly. Managed to install it ignoring some warnings but it would not run. I want to share code to get feedback.

I have a launchpad account, signed terms and coditions, created a ppa. I got my commandline to talk to lauchpad using the encription key.

But when I run $quickly release or $quickly share and it says the project does not exist.

There seems to be another command $dput ... But i don't seem to get the wording right because it requests some sort of signed file that i cannot manage to add the correct way.

Following the indications below I created a project. But when using $quickly release and $quickly share I get the following:

```
    kamehouse@kamehouse-desktop:~/mybrowser$ quickly releaseObtener preferencias de Launchpad
Hay conexión con Launchpad
No Launchpad project set, leave blank to abort.
Launchpad project name: borra2
---------------- [1] ----------------
   toddler game for uncovering images
--------------------------------------
Nombre del proyecto: borrados
URL en Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/borra2
This would be a very similar activity to the "erase" in gcompris. the idea is to access directly to te game and ake it "toddler proof" idealy it should work on touch screens.

Elija su número de proyecto, leave blank to abort, 0 for another search.
Your choice: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/release.py", line 154, in <module>
    print(_("%s does not exist. Please create it on launchpad if you want to push a package to it. %s has the following ppas available:") % (e, ppa_user.name))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
Error: la orden release ha fallado
Cancelando
kamehouse@kamehouse-desktop:~/mybrowser$ quickly share
Obtener preferencias de Launchpad
Hay conexión con Launchpad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/share.py", line 127, in <module>
    print(_("%s does not exist. Please create it on launchpad if you want to push a package to it. %s has the following ppas available:") % (e, ppa_user.name))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
Error: la orden share ha fallado
Cancelando
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem regarding the "no project", there is a difference between a project and PPA.

In order to use the "quickly submitubuntu" command and or share or release, you need to set up a project in launchpad [here](https://help.launchpad.net/Projects/Registering).

I had problems with the packages submitted to my project not packing, so I ended up doing it manually, and its not too bad.

--how to package manually below--

I'm not an expert, so I can only tell you how I managed to get it working for myself.

Make sure your app runs out of /opt too. running "quickly package --extras" will build it this way.

You can then sign it with "debuild -S -k[your key here with no space between it and the k!]"

To find your key if you don't know it, run "gpg --list keys", and on the pub line, your key begins after the forward slash (don't include the date). 
once the package has been signed, run "dput ppa:[username]/[ppa name] [path of source.changes file]" and it should upload it.

If your packages are failing to build because of a missing glib module, see [this ask ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156339/launchpad-failed-to-build-after-quickly-submitubuntu)

I did all this with an application which would run after being installed from a package however, so I'm not sure if yours will be able to be compliled by launchpad if it does not run, but who knows...

exclude "[" and "]" when building the commands.

Comment: thanks! got as far as gettring project up! https://launchpad.net/borra2 I'll try again latr this week! i am so very exited now!

Comment: excited* typo error.